# Что происходит при вызове ассинхронной функции через async await?

Tags: c#, unity3d, async-await

Можно ли запускать ассинхронные задачи через конструкцию _?

Например

```
_ = showText("текст исчезнет через 3 секунды");
```

При том что функция showText ассинхронная?

```
async Task showText(){
  await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Я правильно понимаю что происходит следующее?

```
void mainFunc(){
       int a = .....;  
       _ = showText("текст исчезнет через 3 секунды");
       int b = .....;
}
```

1. В функции mainFunc вычисляется переменная а.
2. Создается новый поток в котором выполняется функция showText
3. Вычисляется переменная b
4. Через 3 секунды функция showText вернет void и поток полностью закроется и высвободит все ресурсы?
5. Таких потоков можно создать одновременно например 2000 без ущерба для производительности?

Comment: Если вы не используете результат работы функции, то нет разницы присваиваете вы его куда-то или нет. При вызове без `await` не будет ожидания окончания работы задачи, если код завершит работу, то и задача прервётся, не доработав до конца, если я правильно помню. В остальном всё правильно вроде более-менее. Хотя потоки и асинхронность это не одно и то же, асинхронность может успешно работать и при одном потоке, поэтому вы можете создать почти сколько угодно задач такого вида с пустым ожиданием, они будут спокойно ждать в фоне.

Comment: @CrazyElf `если код завершит работу` если приложение (текущий процесс) завершит работу.

Comment: @aepot Я это и имел в виду. Никак не получается написать так, чтобы нельзя было что-то понять неправильно )